# Lambda Function to Select/Read Data from RDS and Insert it to another RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I would like to select/read a small data Data from my RDS Database and Insert it to another RDS Database or S3 using Lambda Function. Would it be possible to do so? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the below link to read the data using BOTO3.  After reading the data, just add another code to copy it to the S3 bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html